# Creating home button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have created an application which has 3 activities named as `HOME, About, Contact`. Each activity has a button, `Home` has a button, clicking it `About` activity is started and `About` activity has another button which will open up `Contact` activity. My problem is to go back from `Contact` activity to `Home` activity. How can I achieve it? I had tried to put a button and set up a new `intent`, starting it by `startActivity(newIntent)`. When I click `Home Button` in the contact page the emulator asks me to choose which activity I want to launch. What I am thinking is the process is recreated before it is killed. Can anybody suggest me a way to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working properly"? What does it do or not do?

Comment: It asks me to select from two activities which one to be run. It shows the activity name and asks to select any one of them. If I select the second activity which i will be having after pressing activity1's button then the application stops running. This is the problem.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @InbarRose: I asked this question 9 months ago when I joined stackoverflow. Its a low quality question and I don't want to edit it. I have voted it for closing. Please don't embarrass me asking to improve this post. :(

Comment: @Dibya as the owner of the question you can simply delete it if you do not want it to exist anymore. As I came across your question in the close queue I gave the advise to improve, if you do not want to, that is your call. Have a good day.

Comment: @InbarRose: Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead. This is the message I get when I am trying to delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you're looking to do something like this.

In your ACTIVITY1 class you should have something like this:

```
private ACTIVITY1 thisActivity = this;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(thisActivity, HOMEActivity.class));
    }
});
```

In your manifest you should have something like this:

```
<activity android:name="my.app.path.HOMEActivity" />
<activity android:name="my.app.path.ACTIVITY1" />
<activity android:name="my.app.path.ACTIVITY2" />
```

Also make sure the names reflect the correct paths to the activities.

Answer (score 1):

Create and activity called Home first then call the second activity using Intent. User StartActivity to start the new intent.  Now use finish to kill your first activity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding any activity or recreating any activity on the button click just call the finish() in the button click event.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                finish():
             }
         });
     }
```

this will navigate you to home screen directly.

Comment: I want to have two buttons one home and one back button. back button will take me to activity1 how can I do this?

Comment: @Dibya: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html